# Ran out of disk space in /usr/ports partition, how can I build ports?

Tags: openbsd

I installed OpenBSD using the default/automatic partition configuration which only allocated ~4MB to `/usr`. While compiling a large port it gave an error that the disk was full.

I have looked for ways to extend to the partition but can find nothing about how to do this. I have plenty of space on other partitions (such as `/home`), is there a way to redirect where output files go when I run `make` so I can point them to somewhere that has space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file `/etc/mk.conf` with something like the following:

```
WRKOBJDIR=/home/foo/build/ports
DISTDIR=/home/foo/build/distfiles
PACKAGE_REPOSITORY=/home/foo/packages
```

The path can be to anywhere you want, so obviously replace `/home/foo` with the directory you want. You don't need to create the directories; they will be created automatically when you run `make`.

This is covered in the FAQ: [15.3.3 - Configuration of the ports system](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#PortsConfig), with the suggested use-case of using this to create a "read only" ports tree, so /usr/ports can be on a read-only disk/filesystem and you can still build from it, but obviously still works as a workaround for any situation where you cannot write to /usr/ports.

Answer (score 5):

[Glass's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/635290/193502) is the best way to go, but as an alternative you can move it and symlink it.

```
mv /usr/ports /home/
ln -s /home/ports /usr/ports
```